# Proof all possible unions of a collection of sets is a sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory

If one lets $\Omega$ be a probability space, and S =  $\{A_1, A_2, ... \}$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega$, then I would like to prove that the set of all possible unions of elements in S is a $\sigma$ algebra if we include $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ which is needed by definition.

This is the $\sigma$ algebra generated by S, but I have not seen a proof that it is even a $\sigma$ algebra at all.

Comment: Think harder, this is in general *not* enough to get the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S$. E.g. consider all open rational intervals in $[0,1]$ (Lebesgue measure).

Comment: You need complements as well?

Comment: @copper.hat Sure, and intersections. And then unions and intersections of those, and their complement, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong: try $\Omega=\{a,b\}$ and $A_n=\{a\}$ for every $n$.